# NSUserDefaults key becomes nil when sent between view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I need to send a username between two view controllers so that the second view controller knows who to send a message to. I have tried prepareForSegue, however I have found that the variable passed cannot be dynamically altered. I decided to use NSUserDefaults, which worked very well for the length of my development process. Today, it stopped working. I do not think I deleted anything or made an changes, but nevertheless NSUserDefaults is no longer reliably carrying the value between the two view controllers. Every once in a while (maybe 20% of the time?) the value will be correctly passed. The rest of the time, nothing comes through.
Code:
Set key:

```
func chooseFriend(sender: UIButton) {
        let requestIndex = sender.tag
        let friendChosen = self.friends.objectAtIndex(requestIndex) as! String
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue("thisisatest", forKey: "testKey")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toChat", sender: self)
    }
```

Note: In the viewDidLoad I set testKey = ""
Retrieve key on new view controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let theKey = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("testKey")
        print("The Key: \(theKey)")

        refreshTable()
        let swipe: UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboard")
        swipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Down
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipe)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
        testLabel.text = ""
        self.messages.addObject("Loading......")
    }
```

Every time, the default comes up empty: The Key: Optional()
I can successfully print the default after setting it, however it disappears once I am segued to the next view controller...
If anyone else has experienced this problem please let me know.
Thanks

Randy's code:

```
func chooseFriend(sender: UIButton) {
        let requestIndex = sender.tag
        let friendChosen = self.friends.objectAtIndex(requestIndex) as! String
        // Instantiate the second view controller via t's identifier in the storyboard
        if let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ChatVC") as? chatViewController {
            // Set the chosen friend
            secondViewController.friendChosen = friendChosen
            self.presentViewController(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Added this to destinationviewcontroller:

```
var friendChosen: String!
```

Comment: use setObject:forKey: and objectForKey: instead

Comment: You should really pass the data via `prepareForSegue`. Not sure what you mean by "the variable passed cannot be dynamically altered".

Comment: @jcaron I mean I cannot pass a variable with prepareForSegue that has been changed since when it is instantiated. I create the variable friendChosen = "", but I will need to change it to a name. When I do this, prepareForSegue does not recognize the changed variable

Comment: @NickPitoniak, how and where did you define the property? If you have `var friendChosen : String` in your destination viewController, then in your `prepareForSegue` you simply use `let myController = segue.destinationViewController as! yourdestinationcontrollertype` then `myController.friendChosen = whateveryouneedtosetitto`

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, this type of information *should* be passed from view controller to view controller in a model via a delegate. That would be the "appropriate" way to achieve this behavior via a true MVC pattern.

Having said that; I think the quickest fix for you would be not to use segues and to avoid `NSUserDefaults` all together.

Try the following...

```
func chooseFriend(sender: UIButton) {
    let requestIndex = sender.tag
    let friendChosen = self.friends.objectAtIndex(requestIndex) as! String
    // Instantiate the second view controller via it's identifier in the storyboard
    if let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewControllerIdentifier") as? SecondViewController {
        // Set the chosen friend
        secondViewController.friendChosen = friendChosen
        self.presentViewController(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

And in the `SecondViewController` add the following property.

```
var friendChosen: String!
```

**Please make sure the value is not nil prior to passing it to the destination view controller**

Comment: I encountered this: http://i.imgur.com/eDRn0u4.jpg? I think I am doing something wrong with the friendChosen variable in the second view controller?

Comment: Try adding a friendChosen property to the SecondViewController. I will update my answer to reflect the same.

Comment: It is still unable to alter the friendChosen property on the destination view controller. I will add my code to my original question. Please take a look if you get a chance.

Comment: Sounds to me like the value is nil before it even gets passed to the destination view controller!

Answer (score 0):

The methods for `NSUserDefaults` are `setObject:forKey:` and `objectForKey:`, not `setValue:forKey:` (Or look at the special methods for specific object types, like `setBool:forKey:` or `stringForKey:` (I don't think there's a custom set method for strings.))

The methods with "value" in their names are KVC methods.

But, as Randy says, using your app's model is a better way to go, or passing the information directly to a property in the destination view controller in prepareForSegue. Using NSUserDefaults would not be my first, or my second, choice in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using storyboards already so it should be pretty easy to pass information using `prepareForSegue` like this.

```
class DestinationVC : UIViewController {
  var destName : String!

  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    //configure UI with the destName
    self.label.text = destName
  }

}

class PresentingVC : UIViewController {

  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as? DestinationVC {
      destinationVC.destName = "Some String to Pass"
    }
  }
}
```

As already mentioned NSUserDefaults is not ideal. You will also be loosing type safety and relying on string matching with keys in NSUserDefaults rather than autocompleting and compiler checking with a var on the destinationVC. It's also good practice to limit where your data is kept and where it could be altered. Storing something in NSUserDefaults when the use case is quite confined will make it more difficult to write focussed tests and make it vulnerable to change from any class anywhere in the app. It may be an edge case but starting a pattern like this in your app could expose you to all sorts of side effect bugs in the future.